# What would you recommend to a non-Muslim wanting to learn more about the Islamic faith?

Tags: non-muslim

I am a non-Muslim, a librarian, and an amateur researcher. I'm tired of hearing the media's take on Islam, and want to learn more about the faith and way of life so I can know the truth, instead of the media's spin on it. Where would you suggest I begin my search?

Answer (score 1):

There's resources online:

- Central to Islam is the [Qur'an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quran) and [ahadith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith), which are the natural starting points.  The Qur'an can be downloaded in .pdf form (Google [`quran pdf`](https://www.google.com/search?q=quran%20pdf) for various translations), and ahadith can be found at [sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/) (Sahih al-Bukhari and Sahih Muslim are generally considered reliable).
- There's various [fatwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatwa) (scholarly ruling) sites online; some are more strict (such as [IslamQA.info](https://islamqa.info/en/)) and some are more relaxed (such as [SeekersHub.org](http://seekershub.org/home/)).  I recommend checking multiple sources.

(There's a zillion other webpages, but many are trying to push some kind of "how I interpret Islam is correct" agenda.)

However, to get a realistic understanding of how Islam is practiced, nothing beats getting to know Muslims, or going to Muslim-majority countries and seeing things for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, Rebecca! I will look into those. Unfortunately, international travel isn't an option at the moment, but I will try your other suggestion. I'm just hoping I don't accidentally say or do something that can be construed as offensive.

Comment: @Chelsie, typically "say or do something that can be construed as offensive" for Muslims boils down to insulting Allah or the Prophet. Asking questions of any nature are always welcome long as the words used do not portray mockery, etc. Welcome to Islam SE, , and I hope you find the site useful.